# Show that $A+BC^T$ is nonsingular, and that$ (A+BC^T)^{−1} = A^{−1}−A^{−1}B(I +C^TA^{−1}B)^{−1}C^TA^{−1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Ok, so I've been trying to work on this problem:

Let $n$ and $p$ be positive integers and let $\Bbb F$ be a ﬁeld.
Let $A$ \in $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb F)$ and let $B,C \in M_{n\times p}(\Bbb F)$ be matrices satisfying
the condition that $A$ and $(I + C^TA^{-1}B)$ are nonsingular. Show that $A+BC^T$ is nonsingular, and that  $(A+BC^T)^{-1}$ = $A^{-1}−A^{-1}B(I +C^TA^{-1}B)^{-1}C^TA^{-1}$.
These are some of the properties that I know:
$AB=I_n=BA$
$AA^{-1}=I_n=A^{-1}A$
$(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$
$(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Im assuming that I either have to prove that the above conditions are communitive? Possibly show that they have an inverse? I'm a little bit at a loss on how to do this. Help. Please and Thank you.

Comment: [MathJax works in titles too, don't you know? :)]

Answer (score 2):

Hint: apply the trick in the proof of [Sylvester's determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem), but consider the following equality instead:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}I_n+A^{-1}BC^T&-A^{-1}B\\ 0&I_p\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}I_n&0\\ C^T&I_p\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}I_n&0\\ C^T&I_p\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}I_n&-A^{-1}B\\ 0&I_p+C^TA^{-1}B\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $I+C^TA^{-1}B$ are invertible, then:
\begin{align}
&[A^{-1}-A^{-1}B(I+C^TA^{-1}B)^{-1}C^TA^{-1}][A+BC^T]\\
=&
I-A^{-1}B(I+C^TA^{-1}B)^{-1}C^T+A^{-1}BC^T-A^{-1}B(I+C^TA^{-1}B)^{-1}C^TA^{-1}BC^T\\
=&
I+A^{-1}B[I-(I+C^TA^{-1}B)^{-1}-(I+C^TA^{-1}B)^{-1}C^TA^{-1}B]C^T\\
=&
I+A^{-1}B(I+C^TA^{-1}B)^{-1}\underbrace{[I+C^TA^{-1}B-I-C^TA^{-1}B]}_{=0}C^T\\
=&I.
\end{align}

This already shows that $A+BC^T$ is invertible.