# Linear algebra: proving equality equations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If A and B are square, nonsingular matrices and X is a square matrix, then
$ (A + XBX^T)^{−1} = A^{−1} − A^{−1}X(B^{−1} + X^TA^{−1}X)^{−1}X^TA^{−1} $

This equation so complex, I can't see the key variable to transform and solve it. Plz help me!

Comment: It is in fact a consequence of Sylvester determinant theorem as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/852633)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First premultiply RHS by $A+XBX^T$, you will get identity matrix.

Then postmultiply RHS by $A+XBX^T$, you will get identity matrix again.

Therefore, it will be the inverse of this matrix by definition.

I am showing the procedure for postmultiplication for instance,

$$(A^{-1}-A^{-1}X(B^{-1}+X^TA^{-1}X)^{-1}X^TA^{-1})(A+XBX^T)$$
$\Longrightarrow I+A^{-1}XBX^T-A^{-1}X(B^{-1}+X^TA^{-1}X)^{-1}X^T-A^{-1}X(B^{-1}+X^TA^{-1}X)^{-1}X^TA^{-1}XBX^T$
$\Longrightarrow I+A^{-1}X[B-(B^{-1}+X^TA^{-1}X)^{-1}-(B^{-1}+X^TA^{-1}X)^{-1}X^TA^{-1}XB]X^T$

Now, let $B^{-1}+X^TA^{-1}X = M$,

In order to prove that this expression is I, we have to show that,
$$B-M^{-1}-M^{-1}X^TA^{-1}XB = 0$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow B = M^{-1}(I+X^TA^{-1}XB)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow MB = I+X^TA^{-1}XB$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow M = (I+X^TA^{-1}XB)B^{-1}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow M = B^{-1}+X^TA^{-1}X$$

Hence, this turns out to be I and similarly the other one will be I(After quite lengthy calculation).
Hope it is helpful.

Comment: You mean that I premultiply firstly RHS by $A+XBX^T$, you will get identity matrix. And then, postmultiply LHS by $B^{−1}+X^TA^{−1}X$, you will get identity matrix again. After that, I solve the adjusted equation and get the result which equals iif X is orthogonal matrix.

Comment: I have edited the question to show how it will occur.

Comment: many thanks to you

Comment: For the expression of M, can I expand in this way? $B=M^{−1}(I+X^TA^{−1}XB) \Leftrightarrow MB = I + IX^TA^{-1}XB \Leftrightarrow MI = IB^{-1}+IX^TA^{-1}XI$, then I get the result

Comment: That is what I am doing in the last step.